# How does interrupting a future work with single thread executors?

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executor

How does `Executor.newSingleThreadExecutor()` behave if I am frequently scheduling tasks to run that are being cancelled with `future.cancel(true);`?

Does the single thread spawned by the executor get interrupted (so the future code needs to clear the interrupt), or does the interrupt flag get automatically cleared when the next future starts up.

Does the Executor need to spawn an additional thread on every interrupt to be used by the remaining task queue?

Is there a better way?

Comment: The `Future`, you’re calling `cancel` on, usually is a `FutureTask` which already handles clearing cancellation interrupts after the execution. In case, the interruption happens while the task is running. Otherwise, the executor’s thread doesn’t get interrupted at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, I don't find this documented anywhere, so I would say it is implementation dependent.

For example OpenJDK does reset the interrupted flag before every executed task:

```
// If pool is stopping, ensure thread is interrupted;
// if not, ensure thread is not interrupted.  This
// requires a recheck in second case to deal with
// shutdownNow race while clearing interrupt
if ((runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP) ||
     (Thread.interrupted() &&
      runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP))) &&
    !wt.isInterrupted())
    wt.interrupt();
```

Snippet from from [OpenJDK jdk8u ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/6be37bafb11a/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#l1127).

Answer (score 1):

The following sample program demonstrates that the interrupt is called on the thread if you call the cancel method with true. You can even see that it is reusing the same thread. The cancel returns a boolean which indicates if the cancellation was successful. The javadoc of this method is also clear enough.

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread name = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
            return "Interruped";
        }
        return "X";
    }
}
public class Testy {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService =
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Iteration " + count++);
            Future<String> submit = executorService.submit(new Task());
            Thread.sleep(500);
            submit.cancel(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Output looks like below

```
Iteration 0
Thread name = pool-1-thread-1
Iteration 1
Interrupted
Thread name = pool-1-thread-1
Iteration 2
Interrupted
```

Comment: Bravo for writing a test. However, this doesn't test the behavior in the case the interrupt flag is not cleared by the task, which is what the OP is asking for.